# Rust - idiomatic way to check if a string starts with one of a set of substrings

Tags: string, rust

> ```rust
> core::str
> pub fn starts_with<'a, P>(&'a self, pat: P) -> bool
> where
>     P: Pattern<'a>,
> ```
>
> Returns true if the given pattern matches a prefix of this string slice.
>
> Returns false if it does not.
>
> The pattern can be a `&str`, `[char]`, a slice of `[char]`s, or a function or closure that determines if a character matches.

What's the idiomatic way to see if a string starts with one of a set of substrings?

```rust
if applesauce.starts_with(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) {
    // elegant if you're looking to match a single character
}

if applesauce.starts_with("aaa") || applesauce.starts_with("bbb") || applesauce.starts_with("ccc") || applesauce.starts_with("ddd") {
    // there *must* be a better way!
}
```

Comment: You can use a regex, but I don't think this will be better or faster in any way. You can build a small helper function to help you with that.

Comment: Whether it's faster or not really depends on the size and number of needles, in addition to the size of the haystack. The question as asked is unclear on those parameters.

Comment: OP, if you have a few small strings and you want to search a small string, then using `starts_with` repeatedly is quite fine. But if you need to scale it up, you should use the [`aho-corasick`](https://docs.rs/aho-corasick/) crate. You don't need to bring in all of `regex` for it. (`regex` would just use `aho-corasick` internally anyway, in all likelihood.) As always, benchmark it if performance matters.

Answer (score 5):

You can use iterators:

```rust
if ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"].iter().any(|s| applesauce.starts_with(*s)) {
    // there *must* be a better way!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76964109/11527076) (which is the more pertinent for the question).
In the same idea, if you want to obtain the prefix that matches, you can use `.find()`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let applesauce = "bbbanana";
    if let Some(s) = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
        .iter()
        .find(|s| applesauce.starts_with(*s))
    {
        println!("{:?} starts with {:?}", applesauce, s);
    }
}
/*
"bbbanana" starts with "bbb"
*/
```